# How does compose know when and which to recompose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-livedata

```
@Composable
fun Screen() {
    val viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()
    val listOfID = viewModel.list.observeAsState()
    val liveScores = viewModel.liveScores.observeAsState()

    LazyColumn {
        items(listOfID.value.orEmpty()) { id ->
            AnotherComposable(id = id, liveScores = liveScores)
        }
    }
}
```

liveScores is a `HashMap` that maps an ID to something else. Its value gets reassigned in the VM every 5 seconds. The IDs are the exact same, but the properties of the other object could change.

In AnotherComposable, the `ID` is used to access the object, and that object's properties are used as inputs for more `Composables`.

My question is, when liveScores.value is reassigned inside the view model, how does compose know to only `recompose` the AnotherComposable that use the changed data? Since liveScores is being reassigned, shouldn't all the AnotherComposable be `recomposed`, as they all take liveScores as input?

Comment: If you are mapping the liveScores by id and the content of each object could change, but most of them keep the same, then I might say, it is recomposing but the Ui changes are not visible since the data is the same for those objects without changes. Are you using the Layout Inspector -> Recomposition count? with that tool, you can see if the list items (at least the visible ones) are recomposing every time the `liveScores` is re-assigned..

Comment: @WilsonCastiblanco unfortunately the device I am testing with is below API 29 so I cannot use this feature. However, I have used the debugger and placed breakpoints at the `AnotherComposable` function. It is only being called for the items that have changed